# Multivariate mixture models with INLA: Relating CAR random effect to the MVN covariance matrix

Tags: multivariate-analysis, spatial, gaussian-mixture-distribution, inla

For a research project I am trying to implement a multivariate mixture model on areal data using Integrated Nested Laplace Approximation (INLA). Let $y_{i,d}$ be a data point, where $i = 1, 2, \cdots, N$ is the observation and $d = 1,2,\cdots,D$ is the variable. At the top-level, I wish to specify my mixture model as:

$$
\textbf{y}_{i,\cdot} \sim \sum_{g=1}^G w_g \mathcal{N}(\mu_g, \Sigma_g)
$$
where $g=1,2,\cdots,G$ is the mixture component. As I understand INLA, it then only models the means, $\mu_g$, using a linear predictor. Here I am interested in using spatial random effects (i.e. multivariate CAR random effect). What's confusing me now, is that at the top level, it seems like INLA still models $\Sigma_g$ as a diagonal matrix with zeroes on the off diagonal, while the linear predictor becomes something like:

$$
\mu_g = \alpha_g + \textbf{s}_{i,\cdot}
$$

where $\textbf{s}$ is distributed as a multivariate conditional autoregressive model.

When only putting structured random effects in the linear predictor of the mean, do we still affect $\Sigma_g$ in some way? Thank you.